# Solving differential equation first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me with calculation, or with method I can do it by myself.

Maybe $$y=uv?$$
$$
y'=\frac{x+y-2}{y-x-4}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- This is a first order nonlinear equation
- Rewrite it as $M dx + N dy = 0$
- Test to see if it is an exact equation
- Solve to get:

$$y(x) = x \pm \sqrt {2} \sqrt{x^2+2 x+c_1}+4$$

Comment: Nice hints! "Just right"... $+ \overset{+}{1} + $

Comment: @amWhy: I am going to try the approach of guiding them through the solution, with what I hope are helpful hints. The jury is still out. I feel sometimes answering questions in detail as it is likely doing their HW. You know I always struggle with the right balance!